# Javascript - Conditional property on object

Tags: javascript, object, conditional-statements

I have the following two arrays:

```
let arr1 = [{userId:"myUID1", name: "Dave"},{userId: "myUID2", name: "John"}]
let arr2 = [{userId: "myUID3", dogs: 5}, {userId:"myUID1", children: 0}]
```

I want to find the object with `userId == "myUID1"` in `arr2` and check whether it has the property `children`.

Since `arr2[1]` is `userId == "myUID1"` and has `children` property I would like to add the following property to `arr1[0]`:

```
let arr1 = [{userId:"myUID1", name: "Dave", hasChildren: true},{userId: "myUID2", name: "John"}]
```

I wish to repeat this for all objects in `arr1` and add the `hasChildren` property to each one of them if in `arr2` the object with the same `userId` holds a `children` property.

What would be the best way to achieve the result I desire?

Comment: You can iterate it in any way you want. Try [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), `for`, `forEach`, etc

Comment: use a for loop? where are you stuck? you can write a for loop and test each element's userId property for equality. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is the [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method:

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array
>   that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is
>   returned.

But you can also do it iterating the array with each, forEach, etc.

**Check the explained snippet:**

```js
let arr1 = [{userId:"myUID1", name: "Dave"},{userId: "myUID2", name: "John"}];
let arr2 = [{userId: "myUID3", dogs: 5}, {userId:"myUID1", children: 0}];

//first we find the item in arr2. The function tells what to find.
var result2 = arr2.find(function(item){return (item.userId == "myUID1");});

//if it was found...
if (typeof result2 === 'object') {
  //we search the same id in arr1 
  var result1 = arr1.find(function(item){return (item.userId == result2.userId);});
  //and add the property to that item of arr1
  result1.hasChildren=true;
  
  //and print it, so you can see the added property
  console.log (arr1);
}
```